# I have over written my Ctrl+V function with a macro - how do I restore the original back again

Tags: keyboard, macros, microsoft-word-2010

I have over written my Ctrl+V function with a macro - how do I restore the original back again.  I have lost the paste function of this shortcut key by over writing it with a macro.

Comment: Delete the macro? Change the macro short cut key?

Comment: Of course, how simple?  It worked, thank you

Answer (score 0):

#### I have over written my Ctrl+V function with a macro

> How do I restore the original function back again?

One of the following will resolve your issue:

- Delete the macro
- Change the macro shortcut to something other than <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>